# Hash table design to implement `nextElement()` in constant time

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

I was asked how I would design a hash table that allowed me to implement `nextElement()` in constant time.

My answer was that to avoid checking those buckets that are empty, we could add the elements that are added to the hash to a double-linked list.

If we are asked to iterate over the elements of the hash table we just need to traverse the list from head to end. When an element is removed from the hash, the removal from the list is done in constant time as well.

Of course, this requires extra space for the list and the pointer to next/prev.

Is this approach OK? Better alternatives?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**  I changed the title to make it more precise

Comment: Constant time w.r.t. what? It's going to be at least linear in the number of elements.

Comment: I reworded the question to make it a bit more concise.

Comment: +1, I assume you mean nextElement() in constant time only in case you know the previous element based on your design suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this question.
Iterate over all elements is certainly an `O(N)` operation and can not be done in constant time.
With your list that you say you are just saving a series of `table[i]==null` operations that don't really add any overhead to the loop.

Comment: I think the operation we want to be O(1) is "step forward in an iterator". And checking every bucket means this is O(n) worst case, even though it's expected O(1) and does not change the O(n) time complexity of `for item in hashtable: <O(1) operation>`. (Edit: Confirmed by OP, -1)

Comment: As @delnan says I'm interested in making the "step forward in an iterator" operation O(1).

Comment: @delnan:It is `O(N)` traversals but not `O(N)` comparisons.The expensive operation is the comparison of the objects. The `==null` is trivial and does not account for overhead

Comment: @Cratylus Even if `==null` is inexpensive, you would be checking in O(M) where M is the number of buckets.

Comment: More formally, even if the `== null` operation takes only one cycle, you still need up to M comparisions to find the next bucket which contains an item, and hence O(M) time (worst case). And since the number of buckets is proportional to the number of items, O(M) == O(n) for many hash tables. Big Oh is not about practical performance (how cheap an operation is does not matter), it's about asymptotic growth.

Comment: So @delnan, does it make sense to implement such optimization (list) or in terms of asymptotic growth we can assume that O(M) == O(n) so there is no gain?

Comment: @jjju In terms of asymptotic growth, a loop like `for item in hashtable: ...` is not affected because it's O(n) anyway. I was just arguing that "loop through buckets until you find a non-empty one" requires, in the worst case, `O(n)` checks for bucket emptiness.

Comment: @delnan:1)`you still need up to M comparisions...and hence O(M)`.This is `O(M)` yes **but** it is same as doing `O(M)` traversals.It is different than doing a comparison.2)`the number of buckets is proportional to the number of items, O(M) == O(n)` This is wrong.The hash tables have more capacity than the actual containing elements and also with the `O(M)==O(n)` you are comparing different things.It is like binary search on a doubly linked list. You would be comparing the `O(M)` link traverals (here the `==null` with the `O(logN)` comparisons (here `O(N)` comparisons for the actual elements)

Comment: @delnan:One more thing.When I posted the answer the OP was not modified to say that the interest is in the next element

Comment: (1) I'm not sure what point you are trying to make, is one of those `O(M)` supposed to be `O(<something else>)`? (2) Note that I restrict that statement to some hash table implementations. Many hash table implementations adjust the number of buckets to be never less than `a * n` for some load factor `a`. I do think it is valid to compare these two metrics, because then `M = k * n` (best case, it may be larger if the bin array is never shrunk when entries are removed) and `k * n = O(n)` for some constant k.

Comment: @delnan:1)I am just making a distinction like it is done in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29 which differentiates among link traversals and comparisons.Do you think this is not a good analogy here?

Comment: That does not make sense, for so many reasons I suspect you're confused as to what we are discussing. When enumerating buckets, there are only checks whether each list contains items, but no list traversal because the buckets are stored in an array. When enumerating items in a bucket, there are no comparisions because we only move from one item to the next one. You might argue that a comparision is needed to detect the end, but this happens in lockstep with moving forward and the number thus never differs, so it does not make sense to distinguish them.